# Configuring an SSH tunnel with Forklift

Tags: macos, ssh, tunnel, sftp

Is there any way to configure [ForkLift](http://www.binarynights.com/forklift/) so that it connects to an SFTP server through some SSH tunnel? (without having to launch the SSH tunnel via command line)

E.g., with WinSCP on Microsoft Windows, I can do the following:

[image]

Comment: Use OpenSSH and it's `~/.ssh/config`, which will make it working for you in all Windows/Apple, though it will not be fancy-clicking stuff.